# Solve system of first-order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Not really sure how to solve these at all.. and can't really find the exact words to google.

[image]

Given that system of equations, I need to solve for x(T), Y(T)  and z(T)

I am given then initial conditions: 
[image]

If someone could show me how to do this it would be really awesome!

Comment: Hmmm ... did you try Googling "Solve system of first-order differential equations"?

Comment: Kept getting results for lots of 2nd Order equations.. If you don't want to help me thats fine.

Comment: I tried that search and the first hit was http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsIntro.aspx second hit was the same site, third hit was http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-LinearSystems.pdf which is titled "Systems of First Order Linear Differential Equations". Admittedly Paul's Notes digresses a bit into how to convert higher-order equations into linear systems, but if you just finish reading the page he gets back to the linear systems soon enough.

Comment: Anyway "how to do this" could be an entire chapter of a book, depending on what you know already. This site works best if you can get yourself part of the way through the problem, show what you did so people understand what you understood, and if you get stuck someone can help you get unstuck.